# What are the Swagger advantages over coreapi?

Tags: django, swagger

I'm new to the Django restframework world. I've played around with  [coreapi](http://www.coreapi.org/specification/document/) library to make Linux bash scripts to call my API.

I'm confused of the potential advantages of swagger to do something like this. I know many people are using swagger for documentation, but for my use case (calling it from the linux command line from a shell script) doesn't seem to be a good fit.

Am I missing something huge from Swagger that I'll regret later down the road?

Comment: Swagger community might help you! http://swagger.io/irc/